# VBA If statments run fine on their own but not together too many arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

These IF statements run fine on their own and work, but together they give me too many arguments error?

```
=IF(AND(AND(G11="M2M+",L11="Single"),OR(J11>1180,K11>2430)),Rules!G24,Rules!G23, IF(AND(AND(G11="M2M+",L11="Double"),OR(J11>1180,K11>2430)),Rules!G27,Rules!G28))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gEYH.jpg

Image here of price layout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `if` function has 3 arguments (the indentation is just for explanation purpose):

```
IF(                                                 Arguments in IF
    Something is True,                              (1)
    then do something,                              (2)
    otherwise do something else                     (3)
)
```

If we indent your function the same way, you will clearly see that there are too many arguments (4) in the first `if`.

```
=IF(                                                Argument in IF
    AND(                                            (1)
        AND(G11="M2M+",L11="Single"),
        OR(J11>1180,K11>2430)
    ),
    Rules!G24,                                      (2)
    Rules!G23,                                      (3)
    IF(                                             (4)
        AND(
            AND(G11="M2M+",L11="Double"),
            OR(J11>1180,K11>2430)
        ),
        Rules!G27,                                      
        Rules!G28
    )                                  
)
```

You need to end the first `if` after 3 Arguments with a closing bracket. It's hard to tell how the correct function would look like because we don't know what you are trying to achieve.

There is a possibility that you might be looking for this:

```
=IF(AND(G11="M2M+",OR(J11>1180,K11>2430)), IF(L11="Single",Rules!G24,IF(L11="Double", Rules!G27, Rules!G28)), Rules!G23)
```

Comment: Yeah i've just worked that out but if i close the brackets after 3 it still doesn't work, 4 should be the next IF not a 4th argument

Comment: Yes, because you need to re-think your logic. You can't just append 2 `If`s. I don't know what you are trying to achieve so it's hard to tell how it would look right. I can only tell what is wrong. You are the only person who can tell what the correct function would be.

Comment: its basically getting the correct price basic on G11 and L11 equalling something i.e. Single or Double and then if J11 or K11 are above or below 1180 or 2430

Comment: Typically when you nest an IF statement you start the second IF in the FALSE argument.  If both are false, then the end result is the last false argument.

Comment: Try something like this `=IF(AND(G11="M2M+",OR(J11>1180,K11>2430)), IF( L11="Single", Rules!G24, IF(L11="Double", Rules!G27, Rules!G28)),Rules!G23)`

Comment: It doesn't work like that. see if i can add a picture to the main window

Comment: image link added

Comment: This would be another option: `=IF(L11="Single",IF(   AND(G11="M2M+",OR(J11>1180,K11>2430)), Rules!G24,Rules!G23),IF(L11="Double", IF(   AND(G11="M2M+",OR(J11>1180,K11>2430)), Rules!G27,Rules!G28),"-"))` The image is quite useless because we can't see the cells names and we don't know your goal. I think we showed what is wrong but it is up to you to get it right.

Comment: Peh - Your a star.... that works well enough to get me on my way.... much better logic and shorter code!!